# Magento 2 Js files are not loading from pub/static in my custom module

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, requirejs

Magento 2 Js files are not loading from pub/static in my custom module
Js file path as: `app/code/vendor/name/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/columns/thumbnail.js`
Even above file is available in `static/version1636461000/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Vendor_Name/js/grid/columns/thumbnail.js`
but when I inspect from browser nothing is showing

```
NOTE: I have overridden this file from module-Ui
```

Please help me
THanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this from the component defined in the grid UI component file. For example, if you want to modify the thumbnail for Product List Grid, you need to do the following:

1. Create app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
   <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
     <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
      <column name="thumbnail" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Thumbnail" component="VendorName_ModuleName/js/grid/columns/thumbnail" sortOrder="20">
        <settings>
            <altField>name</altField>
            <hasPreview>1</hasPreview>
            <addField>true</addField>
            <label translate="true">Thumbnail</label>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
        </settings>
      </column>
     </columns>
   </listing>
   ```

You can find the change here is at line 4

> component="VendorName_ModuleName/js/grid/columns/thumbnail"

2. Now you have to copy **thumbnail.js** from vendor to **app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/columns/thumbnail.js** and modify your changes.

Now the Product grid will use your modified thumbnail.js file instead of vendor.

Comment: Thankyou! resolved

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a proper require-config.js file as Magento uses requireJS to load all JS files and requireJS checks reuquire-config.js

Also you should have the required steps implemented to make sure that the JS is included.

Comment: I did but not working for me